# Chef - Powershell Output

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra

I upgraded to Windows 10 recently and I'm noticing a very strange/annoying issue when running knife commands.

When I run this in the powershell console:

```
$nodes = knife node list
```

The value of `$nodes` is `$null` and all of my nodes are listed in the console window instead of being captured and stored in the `$nodes` variable. When I run that same command from Powershell ISE, it functions as expected where the values of `$nodes` contains my node list.

I've tried several variations, all with the same result...

```
$nodes = & knife node list
$nodes = Invoke-Expression -Command 'knife node list'
$nodes = $(Invoke-Expression -Command 'knife node list')
$nodes = & knife node list 2>&1
$nodes = & knife node list 3>&1
$nodes = & knife node list 4>&1
```

What is going on where my powershell console session cannot capture the output from the ruby interpreter but powershell ise session can!?

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.122
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.122
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Tried with and without the chef powershell module: `Import-Module Chef` same result.

```
PS C:\Users\nhudacin> chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.12.0
chef-client version: 12.8.1
berks version: 4.3.0
kitchen version: 1.6.0
```

Now here's the kicker... I would just use ISE to get it done, but this command:

```
$nodes = knife exec -E 'b = Time.now.to_i;a = (b - (336*60*60)).to_i;printf "%-40s %-23s\n", "Name", "Last Check-In";search(:node, "ohai_time:[0 TO #{a}]") { |n| checkIn = Time.at(n["ohai_time"]).strftime("%F %R"); printf "%-40s %-23s\n", n.name, checkIn;}'
```

works perfectly in powershell console, returning a list of nodes that hasn't checked-in within the last 14 days. When I run it in ISE, it doesn't return a single node (even though I know there are at least 10 that meet this criteria).

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution for this yet? My knife-fu is seriously hampered by this irritation.

Comment: No solution yet. The problem seems to come and go. I can again execute the above knife commands in Powershell ISE & Console. No clue what changed.

Comment: If you run the command without the variable `knife node list` does it work as expected? Could you also try the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/Persistent13/afc29d324ef1b6068e1990ea6c52c4d9) and see if the `$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` section contains the expected output as well?

Comment: I just tried `$nodes = knife node list` in my PowerShell console window and everything functioned as I would expect it to, `$nodes` contained my list of nodes. Same version of chef/chefdk as before. Maybe a windows update fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the chef module that is installed as part of the ChefDK. That is what fixed this problem for me.

```
Remove-Module chef
```

https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4045

Comment: You are awesome! :)